# Java JDBC: how to get int size of table, by exectuning SQL query

Tags: java, jdbc

Part of my code looks like this:

```
int size = 0;

        try {

            String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM users";

            statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.execute(query);
```

I don't know what to do to set size of table to my int size.

Answer (score 2):

The result set will contain the value of numner of rows. get the value into your size variable.

```
  ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
  while (result.next()){
  size= result.getInt(1);
  }
  System.out.println("Number of row:"+size);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to ResultSet

Comment: @RichardK: then you are not running the code in vembutech's answer.

Comment: I see it, preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
   resultset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

Answer (score 0):

int size = 0;

```
    try {

        String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM users";

        statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = statement.execute(query);
        size = rs.getInt(1);
```

rs.getInt(1) will return the first row from the query as int

Comment: "*rs.getInt(1) will return the first row*" no it will not. It will return the first **column** from the  result set. An you **have** to call `rs.next()` before you can call any `getXXX()` method.